# How to calculate & report on the time between two specific Stages?

Tags: reporting, formula-field, opportunity-history

I’m trying to calculate the amount of time it takes for an opportunity to move to a specific stage after being created.

For example, Client A moves through the following stages:

- First Contact: 3 days
- Cultivating: 182 days
- Proposal: 152 days
- Verbal Commit: 6 days
- Closed Won: final stage

For Client A, it took 343 days to reach “Verbal Commit.” I’d like to run a report that calculates this for all clients from the previous FY.

Any ideas on how to calculate (and run a report on) the days passed between “Created Date” and the date an Opportunity was moved to a specific stage? We do NOT want the days passed between "Created Date" and “Last Modified” or “Closed” date.

Comment: A custom formula field on Opportunity object or a row-level formula in the report

Comment: Sorry @identigral, I didn't see your reply earlier! Here's what I mentioned below about the custom formula field: I tried doing this, but was having trouble creating a formula that would capture what I am interested in. So far, I have not been able to create a formula that subtracts the "Date moved from Stage X" - "Created Date." Any ideas on how to generate this?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a custom formula on the Object that adds up the days required, but the better option would be a row-level formula in the report itself if your report can support it!

[image: Visual from the Reporting Dashboard]

Comment: Looks like Identigral beat me to it!

Comment: Hi Jacob, thanks for your reply! I did try to create a row-level formula within the report to add up the stage durations, but this was very clunky and it is difficult to filter for the clients that reached the stage "Verbal Commit" because not all do.

Comment: I'm really interested in the idea of creating a custom formula on the Object though!  I tried doing this, but was having trouble creating a formula that would capture what I am interested in. So far, I have  not been able to create a formula that subtracts the "Date moved from Stage X" - "Created Date." Any ideas on how to generate this?

Comment: What kind of issues are you running into with the formula? One of the tricky parts is that, **Created Date** is a DateTime field whereas **Date Moved from Stage XX** is likely a Date field. If that's that case you'll need to do something like:

``DateValue(CreatedDate) - Date_Moved_From_Stage_XX__c``

Comment: Sorry I wasn't very clear in the previous message! There is no "Date moved from Stage X" - this is just the information that I'm looking for. Salesforce does record the date and time each stage is updated in the "Stage History" section of the Opportunity record, but we do not have a field to capture this information and insert it into our formula.

Comment: The fully robust solution is complicated - [option 1](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/24949/how-to-create-a-lead-stage-duration-report) or [option 2](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/73890/duplicating-opportunity-stage-duration-for-custom-field). If you're not comfortable with this type of customization, you can get a pretty decent picture of funnel velocity via an out of the box Opportunity History report. You'll have to make assumptions about stage changes and based on these assumptions calculate durations via formulas.

Comment: We're doing a similar solution to the answer to Option 1 in Integrals comment above (Here: [link](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/24953/110873) ) wherein we utilize a fast field update Flow to update custom fields. This also allows the Sales team to easily see on the Page Layout what dates various moves happened. For example, if Stage goes from Open to anything, the flow then updates Date_From_Open__c to today's date. Unfortunately this also means you'll have to backfill all of the data as also mentioned in the link. Let me know if you need help with this and I can walk you through it!